# Sixty-nine callback

Tags: terminology

In the movie 'Fight Club' I heard the phrase 'Sixty-nined you' for calling back. Is that common in American English or special for New York where you can press the 6 and 9 to call the last incoming number?

Comment: That should probably read *star-sixty-nined*.  Without *star*, it has a rather different meaning.

Comment: Also referred to as *star-six-nine*.

Comment: According to [Subzin](http://www.subzin.com/search.php?title=fight+club&imdb=&q=69&search_sort=Popularity&genre=-1&type=All), the subtitles are: *I called a second ago. There was no answer. - I'm at a payphone. - Yeah, I *69'd you. I never pick up my phone.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that pressing <kbd>*</kbd> <kbd>6</kbd> <kbd>9</kbd> used to apply in Canada too, so it was not just a New York thing. The availability of this feature might depend on who your service provider is.

As for using it as a phrase, I do recall hearing it years ago (late 1990's I guess?) in a way similar to what your example, but not so much anymore.

---

Off-topic but purely for the sake of interest, I found a list of star-codes for Bell: http://www.yashy.com/star.codes.html

Most of these I'd never heard of, I don't know if all carriers support all of these.

Comment: I remember many Baby Bells advertising [star codes](http://community.seattletimes.nwsource.com/archive/?date=19970921&slug=2561540) in the '90s after the telecom deregulation as an upsell. Star70 was important so call waiting wouldn't disconnect your dialup Internet. Star69 is probably the best known not only because it was the most used, but because it was an R.E.M. song. *[I know you called - I know you called - I know you hung up my line
Star sixty-nine](http://www.remrock.com/remrock/lyrics_display.php?the_track_id=a09t05)*

Answer (score 1):

This isn't am AmE vs. BE issue really, but rather an issue of 20th Century [American History](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states).

The Phone System in the USA was for generations run by a single monopoly, which we called ["Ma Bell"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_System). After literally generations of anti-trust legal action, the [company was split up](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_System_divestiture) in 1982. However, the system was still designed as one large unit. This meant that when the "baby bells" started offering features like last-call callback in the 90's, they all used the same codes (and it worked no matter where in the system you got that last call from).

So in the 90's, any USA resident could use `*69`. It was being heavily advertised by the Baby Bells (as it cost extra to do so, so more profit for them), so this is something that would have been instantly recognisable across the country. You could put it in a movie or some other mass media in a curt form like you found, and everyone in the US at the time would know what you meant.

These days I suspect they still offer those codes and they still work, but most people use cellphones instead, and pretty much every phone of any kind has caller ID and some kind of caller-ID based dialback feature (rendering *69 pointless). So today most folks who didn't use phones the 90's in the USA would hear that and not know what it is referring to.

Comment: In the UK you dial 1471 to find out who called, and can press 3 to call back; or in one go to call right back: 14713. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last-call_return) has a whole list of country numbers. Both US and Canada use *69.